# Scroll the VerticalGridView or RecyclerView by keeping focus on center element

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, focus, leanback

Scroll the VerticalGridView by keeping focus on center element. I am implementing a verticalgridview with 1 column count and I want to keep the focus on a single item which is in center and move the verticalgridview.[I want to set focus on center object in vertical grid view and scroll the view by fixing the focus there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qkYQ.png)

Comment: not enough details

Comment: @Yashwant Welcome to SO, could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve and what you envision your end result to be?

Comment: @ChrisvinJem I added a image of what I want to achieve. Please check!

Comment: @PradipVadher I added a image of what I want to achieve. Please check!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VerticalGridView contains its built-in layout manager which does exactly that. Do **NOT** use `verticalGridView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager())`, which one would usually do with RecyclerView. By default the focused item of a VerticalGridView is always positioned at the center **unless** the item is at the beginning/end, or there are too few items.

If there are too few items, you can use [`verticalGridView.setWindowAlignment(WINDOW_ALIGN_NO_EDGE)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/BaseGridView.html#setwindowalignment). Now the items at the beginning/end will also be positioned at the center. You can also choose `WINDOW_ALIGN_LOW_EDGE` or `WINDOW_ALIGN_HIGH_EDGE` depending on your needs. The default is `WINDOW_ALIGN_BOTH_EDGE`.

You can also use [`verticalGridView. setWindowAlignmentOffsetPercent (offsetPercent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/BaseGridView.html#setwindowalignmentoffsetpercent) to manually determine the focus position. If `offsetPercent` is 50, the focus is at the center; if it's 90, it's towards the bottom; if it's 10, it' near the top, etc.

Comment: Please provide some more help.

Comment: @RaviRawal I have edited my answer with more detail.